# Proof of Chvátals Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, hamiltonian-path

I was looking through multiple criteria for Hamiltonian circuits and read several papers such as [the following](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjMnf648OTwAhUUt6QKHW8xDRAQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpersonalpages.manchester.ac.uk%2Fstaff%2Fmark.muldoon%2FTeaching%2FDiscreteMaths%2FLectureNotes%2FHamiltonBondyAndChvatal.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3MDpH8d70lse6TlT5snCyn) from the university of Manchester. I was particulary intrigued by a theorem Wolframs Math World references as [Chvátal's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChvatalsTheorem.html), based on degree sequences, not on closure, but I was unable to find a proof for it.

What I am referring to is the following:

Given a graph $G$'s ordered degree sequence $d_1...d_n$,  if for $i<{n\over 2}$ one has that $d_i>i+1$ or $d_{n-i}>n-i$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

I have seen it referenced in multiple stack exchange [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/808266/user808266), but I have not yet seen a proof for it in the literature. Any reference would be very much appreciated, as would any explanation to the easier Bondy-Chvátal theorem.

Thanks a lot

Comment: In Bollobas' "Modern Graph Theory" it is done, Theorem 15 and Corollary 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a web ressource proving it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good deal more of research, I indeed found the answer to the question I was looking for. On Science Direct, one can access Chvátals original paper, "On Hamilton's ideals", where a proof of his theorem can be found.

The link to the paper can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895672900202).